# 3d array movement in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, 3d, processing, p5.js

I'm in dire need of help with a graduation project that I'm working on. What I'm trying to achieve here in the code below is -to put it very simply- to initialize a 3d array of box() objects (this works) and then introduce another box() object (the end goal is to have an array of these as well) to move about within the same 3D grid. The moving unit picks a random location for initialization and a random target for destination (both within the 3D grid).
But the problem is that I need the moving unit not to overlap with the static base units, also move orthogonally, and always move one unit size each time. If I run the code below the moving unit reaches the target but without any of the restrictions that I mentioned above. It just takes the shortest vector and goes there regardless.

PS: Since p5js doesn't support wireframe in webgl mode I tried to show them with some transparency for better visual legibility. Although, the loadImage() functions are still there and could be replaced with any image of your liking to better differentiate units from one another.

I'd sincerely appreciate help with this since I'm also very short on time. Thanks in advance.

Here's the verifiable code:

```
var matrixSize = 5;
var locations = new Array(matrixSize);
var locBool = new Array(matrixSize);

//unit stuff
var unitSize = 40;
var units_a = []
var units_b;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);

    //3D array of location vectors & booleans
    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        locations[i] = new Array(matrixSize);
        locBool[i] = new Array(matrixSize);
        for(var j = 0; j < locations[i].length; j++){
            locations[i][j] = new Array(matrixSize);
            locBool[i][j] = new Array(matrixSize);
            for(var k = 0; k < locations[i][j].length; k++){
                locations[i][j][k] = 
                createVector(i*unitSize, j*unitSize, k*unitSize);
                locBool[i][j][k] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //base units
    var threshold = 2; //decides on the percentage to be initialized
    for (var i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++){
            for(var k = 0; k < matrixSize; k++){
                stateRndm = random(10);
                if(stateRndm <= threshold){
                    state = 1;
                    locBool[i][j][k] = true;
                }else{
                    state = 0
                }
                units_a.push(new UnitOne(
                    i*unitSize,j*unitSize,k*unitSize, state));
            }
        }
    }
    units_b = new UnitTwo(); 
}

function draw() {
    background(20);
    ambientLight(235);
    orbitControl();
    rotateX(10);
    rotateY(-10);
    rotateZ(0);

    //center the window and display the units
    push();
    translate(-unitSize*matrixSize/2, -unitSize*matrixSize/2, 0);
    for(var i = 0; i < units_a.length; i++){
        units_a[i].display();
    }
    units_b.display();
    units_b.update();
    units_b.move();
    pop();
}

function UnitOne (x, y, z, state){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.state = state;

    //this.img = loadImage("assets/tex_1.jpg");

    //basic movement parameters
    this.acceleration = createVector();
    this.velocity = createVector();
    this.location = createVector(this.x, this.y, this.z);


    this.update = function(){
        this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
        this.location.add(this.velocity);
        this.acceleration.mult(0);
    }

    this.display = function(){
        if(this.state == 1){
            push();
            scale(1);
            //texture(this.img);
            ambientMaterial(50, 200, 100, 20);
            translate(this.x, this.y, this.z);
            box(unitSize);
            pop();
        }
    }
}

function UnitTwo() {
    //assign random initial location
    this.selector;
    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < locations[i].length; j++){
            for(var k = 0; k < locations[i][j].length; k++){
                this.selector = createVector(
                    floor(random(i))*unitSize, 
                    floor(random(j))*unitSize, 
                    floor(random(k))*unitSize);
            }
        }
    }
    print(this.selector);

    //assign random target 
    this.targetSelector;
    for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < locations[i].length; j++){
            for(var k = 0; k < locations[i][j].length; k++){
                this.targetSelector = createVector(
                    floor(random(i))*unitSize, 
                    floor(random(j))*unitSize, 
                    floor(random(k))*unitSize);
            }
        }
    }
    print(this.targetSelector);

    //basic movement parameters
    this.location = createVector(
                    this.selector.x,
                    this.selector.y,
                    this.selector.z);
    this.acceleration = createVector();
    this.velocity = createVector();

    this.maxSpeed = 1;
    this.maxForce = 2;

    //this.img = loadImage("assets/tex_2.jpg");

    this.display = function(){
        push();
        //texture(this.img);
        ambientMaterial(200, 100, 40);
        translate(this.location.x, 
                this.location.y, this.location.z);
        scale(1);
        box(unitSize);
        pop();
    }

    this.update = function(){
        this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
        this.location.add(this.velocity);
        this.acceleration.mult(0);
    }
}

UnitTwo.prototype.move = function(){
    var target = createVector(this.targetSelector.x,
                              this.targetSelector.y,
                              this.targetSelector.z);
    var desired = p5.Vector.sub(target, this.location);

    var d = desired.mag();

    //check the distance to slow down
    if (d < unitSize/2)
        desired.setMag(this.maxSpeed/2);
    else
        desired.setMag(this.maxSpeed);

    var steer = p5.Vector.sub(desired, this.velocity);
    steer.limit(this.maxForce);
    this.acceleration.add(steer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've outlined both things you need to do. Which part of them are you stuck on?

**Step 1:** Make your unit move one cube at a time. You could do this by simply adding or subtracting 1 to its x, y, or z coordinate. Get this working first. Don't worry about avoiding collisions with the other cubes yet.

**Step 2:** When you get that working, add code that detects when the cube it's about to move to is occupied, and go in a different direction. You might have to implement a basic path finding algorithm, and Google is your friend for that.

You might also want to consider the possibility that your random generation has blocked all of the paths to the goal. What do you want to do in that case? And one more note: you don't need a triple-nested `for` loop just to generate a random value.

If you get stuck on one of these steps, please narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing just that step before you post again. Good luck.